FSA for 'closure' of a language; how to represent?
Is my interpretation of this correct?
I want to represent a regular language, L(B) as L(A*) where L(A*) represents the closure of L(B), as a DFA.
In order to do so, would I draw a new edge from the starting state to the accepting state with the transition of ε/lamda? Or would I have a new state after the starting state with the transition ε/lamda that then leads into the rest of the FSA?
By closure, I mean when there is the Kleene star after the language, like L*

As far as I can tell, you are asking about constructing an $\epsilon$-NFA $B$ from a DFA $A$; such that $L(B) = L(A)^*$. If yes, please edit the question, and write it more clearly.
Well, your suggestion, where $B$ is obtained from $A$ by adding an $\epsilon$-transition from the initial state of $A$ to every final state of $A$, does not work. To see why, consider for example, the 2-state DFA $A$ for the language $L = \{w\in \{a, b\}^*: \text{$w$ ends with $a$}\}$ (please draw $A$!). Then, note that the resulted automaton $B$ accepts all inputs (and not only the ones in $L(A)^*$). The problem with this suggestion is that by adding an $\epsilon$-transition from the initial state to a final state, you are allowing $B$ to accept more words than needed as you break the structure of $A$, and introduce new runs that consist also of rejecting runs of $A$.
Hint: The automaton B, on input $w$, should simulate the run $A$ on $w$, and whenever $A$ reaches a final state, $B$ should guess to either:
(1) move to the initial state of $A$ (guessing that we have just read the current infix of $w$ in $L(A)$, and should start reading the next infix in $L(A)$). Or,
(2) proceed running as in $A$, guessing we are not done with reading the current infix in $L(A)$ yet.
Notes:
1- $B$ should not break the structure of $A$.
2- The above hint does not care about the empty word $\epsilon$ (note that $\epsilon$ is in the Kleene-star of every language and thus needs to be accepted by $B$). However, it is easy to deal with $\epsilon$, and I leave the details to you.
